# Turn off the prompts of display large color blocks in emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I am working python project on emacs and encounter such a problem

[image]

The annoying color blocks.

The `flycheck`, `flymake` and `flycheck` had all been turned off.

How could let the color blocks go?

It's displayed finely from vscode..

[image]

Comment: Trailing spaces highlighted?

Comment: oh, thank you, I searched just now, and it is spaces highlighted.

Comment: Could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @AlexKroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variable `show-trailing-whitespace` to `nil`.

In fact, that's the default value for that variable, so there might be a line in your init file that sets it to `t`.